# How use the custom key in openssl in AES_set_encrypt_key

Tags: c++, c, encryption, openssl

I try implement the encode and decode using openssl, [using a code how example](http://www.firmcodes.com/how-do-aes-128-bit-cbc-mode-encryption-c-programming-code-openssl/), but when i try use a custom key, the code broken, what is the currect form to set a custom key and a custom input to use in openssl (I believe that the error is in my logic in C and not at use of openssl)

```
    const char *in = "test";

    size_t in_len = strlen(in);
    unsigned char aes_input[in_len];
    for (size_t i = 0; i != in_len; i++) aes_input[i] = in[i];
//
//    const char *my_custom_key = "my_custom_key";
//    size_t key_len = strlen(my_custom_key);
//    unsigned char aes_key[key_len];
//    for (size_t i = 0; i != in_len; i++) aes_input[i] = my_custom_key[i];
//
    unsigned char aes_key[] = {0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xAA, 0xBB,
                               0xCC,
                               0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF};

    /* Init vector */
    unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
    memset(iv, 0x00, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

    /* Buffers for Encryption and Decryption */
    unsigned char enc_out[sizeof(aes_input)];
    unsigned char dec_out[sizeof(aes_input)];

    /* AES-128 bit CBC Encryption */
    AES_KEY enc_key, dec_key;
    AES_set_encrypt_key(aes_key, sizeof(aes_key) * 8, &enc_key);
    AES_cbc_encrypt(aes_input, enc_out, sizeof(aes_input), &enc_key, iv, AES_ENCRYPT);
    /* AES-128 bit CBC Decryption */
    memset(iv, 0x00, AES_BLOCK_SIZE); // don't forget to set iv vector again, else you can't decrypt data properly
    AES_set_decrypt_key(aes_key, sizeof(aes_key) * 8, &dec_key); // Size of key is in bits
    AES_cbc_encrypt(enc_out, dec_out, sizeof(aes_input), &dec_key, iv, AES_DECRYPT);
```

The code above it is work, but if i change to use my custom key, it is breaks

```
    const char *my_custom_key = "my_custom_key";
    size_t key_len = strlen(my_custom_key);
    unsigned char aes_key[key_len];
    for (size_t i = 0; i != in_len; i++) aes_input[i] = my_custom_key[i];

//    unsigned char aes_key[] = {0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xAA, 0xBB,
                               0xCC,
                               0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a text string as AES key is not a good idea because:

1. An AES key must be exactly `AES_KEY_LENGTH` bytes in size.
   `"my_custom_key"`, being 13 bytes, is too short.
2. ASCII text has low entropy, and will severely reduce the security of the encryption.

The standard solution to this is to use a [key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function), e.g. PBKDF2, in order to "strengthen" and pad the key to make it usable for encryption.

If you only care about key size, then a hashing function like SHA-256 will be enough to turn a password into a key of correct size.

Something like this:

```
std::string pass = "my_custom_key";
unsigned char key[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA256_CTX sha256;
SHA256_Init(&sha256);
SHA256_Update(&sha256, pass.data(), pass.size());
SHA256_Final(key, &sha256);
```

Comment: The "my_custom_key" is only a example for this code, the problem is the code breaks, with error SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) when execute AES_cbc_encrypt using the aes_key with my custom key and work with the key from example.

Comment: now, i understand. I change the length or key and now has no segment fault

Comment: AES_cbc_encrypt segfaults because  AES_set_encrypt_key before it fails when the key size is wrong. You should check the return value of each call to make sure the call succeeded. Also note that a zero IV is insecure.